# While Testing Firebase httpsCallable functions Firebase Client giving "FirebaseError: internal" Error

Tags: firebase, google-cloud-functions, firebase-tools

#### Steps to Reproduce :

1. Run `firebase init` to initialize the Firebase Configurable. Then select `Functions` and `Emulators`.
2. For Emulators select Functions emulator and ui emulator. Then for Functions emulator assign port as `5001` and for ui assign port as `2000`.
3. For Functions select typescript and let firebase download the dependencies. Then paste the following code in `functions/index.ts` :

```js
import * as functions from "firebase-functions";

export const helloWorld = functions.https.onCall((data, context) => {
    console.log(data);
    return { success : true };
});
```

4. Run `npm run build` inside the `functions/` folder to build the function. Then start the firebase emulator using `firebase emulators: start`
5. Now initialize a new project by installing firebase sdk and initializing the SDK with firebaseConfig as follows **index.ts**:

```js
import { initializeApp } from "firebase/app";
import { connectFunctionsEmulator, getFunctions, httpsCallable } from "firebase/functions";

const firebaseConfig = { /*...firebaseConfig*/ };

const app = initializeApp(firebaseConfig);
const functions = getFunctions(app);
const useEmulator:boolean = true

if(useEmulator) {
    connectFunctionsEmulator(functions, "localhost", 5001);
}

const triggerCallable = httpsCallable(functions, "helloWorld");
const result = await triggerCallable({
    message : "Hello world",
    count: 1
});
console.log(result); // expected : { success : true }
```

6. Run the `index.ts` file with `npm run build && node dist/index.js`, you will get :

```
node:internal/process/esm_loader:97
    internalBinding('errors').triggerUncaughtException(
                              ^

[FirebaseError: internal] {
  code: 'functions/internal',
  customData: undefined,
  details: undefined
}
```

> I am not even getting the function intialized message in the emulator logs. Although I do get `✔  functions: Loaded functions definitions from source: helloWorld.`

It looks like the function is not even initializing it correctly. I have also tried with `onCall()` 2nd gen firebase functions and it too has the same result `FirebaseError: internal`

#### Resources :

**firebase.json** :

```js
{
  "functions": [
    {
      "source": "functions",
      "codebase": "default",
      "ignore": [
        "node_modules",
        ".git",
        "firebase-debug.log",
        "firebase-debug.*.log"
      ],
      "predeploy": [
        "npm --prefix \"$RESOURCE_DIR\" run build"
      ]
    }
  ],
  "emulators": {
    "functions": {
      "port": 5001
    },
    "ui": {
      "enabled": true,
      "port": 2000
    },
    "singleProjectMode": true
  }
}
```

**Project Structure** :

```
.
├── database-debug.log
├── dist
│   ├── index.js
│   └── index.js.map
├── firebase-debug.log
├── firebase.json
├── functions
│   ├── lib
│   │   ├── index.js
│   │   └── index.js.map
│   ├── package.json
│   ├── package-lock.json
│   ├── src
│   │   └── index.ts
│   └── tsconfig.json
├── package.json
├── package-lock.json
├── pubsub-debug.log
├── src
│   └── index.ts
├── tsconfig.json
└── ui-debug.log
```

Where my `tsconfig.json` of the client app is :

```js
{
    "compilerOptions": {
        "module": "NodeNext",
        "moduleResolution": "NodeNext",
        "target": "ES2020",
        "sourceMap": true,
        "outDir": "dist"
    },
    "include": ["src/**/*"],
}
```

I have tried everything please somebody help :)
Thanks in advance.

Comment: Have you seen this [section](https://firebase.google.com/docs/emulator-suite/connect_functions?hl=en#instrument-functions) of the documentation about "Instrument your app for callable functions"?

Comment: @RenaudTarnec Yes I have seen that one. I have also tried with that too, but same result.

Comment: I'm not able to replicate using your provided code (I get `{ data: { success: true } }` as expected).
Can you share the function emulator logs to ensure it's starting up correctly? There should be at least 2 lines:
`functions Loaded functions definitions from source: helloWorld.`
and
`functions
http function initialized (http://127.0.0.1:5001/<project-id>/us-central1/helloWorld).`

Comment: @Kiana My emulator do print the `✔  functions: Loaded functions definitions from source: helloWorld.` and 
`✔  functions[us-central1-helloWorld]: http function initialized (http://127.0.0.1:5001/<project-id>/us-central1/helloWorld).`

Comment: @Kiana and alongside those I also get a warning like `⚠  functions: Your requested "node" version "16" doesn't match your global version "18". Using node@18 from host.`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think the problem might be related to https://github.com/nodejs/node/issues/40537. TLDR; starting from Node 17 there was a change to the default IP resolving. By default, it now uses the IPv6 loopback address, which is `::1`.

Since it looks like the emulator is using the host `127.0.0.1`, to resolve this try changing `localhost` to `127.0.0.1`.

```js
if (useEmulator) {
  connectFunctionsEmulator(functions, "127.0.0.1", 5001);
}
```