# "FirebaseError: internal" when calling onCall cloud function from client code

Tags: node.js, firebase, react-native, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-functions

I have a React Native - Expo application, and I recently implemented a basic cloud function using the firebase-functions/v2/https onCall() like so:

```
exports.addmessage = onCall((request) => {
    logger.info("Request: " + request.data.text);
    return {text: request.data.text}
});
```

I deploy this function, and it gets deployed seemingly correct. Then I try to call this function from my client code in the App - component like so:

```
export default function App() {
  const addmessage = httpsCallable(functions, 'addmessage');
  
  function callFunction() {
    addmessage({ text: "Hello world!" })
      .then((result) => {
        console.log("Function called");
        console.log(result);
      }).catch((error) => {
        console.log("Function call failed");
        console.log(error)
      });
  }

  return (
    <SafeAreaProvider>
      <SafeAreaView style={styles.container}>
        <Button title="Call cloud function" onPress={() => callFunction()}></Button>
        <StatusBar style="auto" />
      </SafeAreaView>
    </SafeAreaProvider>
  );
}
```

When I click the button to call the cloud function, I get "Function call failed" and "[FirebaseError: internal]". Is this the correct way to call the callable function?
I have checked the logger for the function inside the firebase portal, but no errors are logged there. What can I do to find/fix this issue?
I have tested with an onRequest-function, and this works as expected.

I use "firebase": "9.22.1" as dependency in project-package.json (though I have also tested with "firebase": "9.20.0")
In my functions package.json, I have these dependencies: "firebase-admin": "^11.8.0", "firebase-functions": "^4.3.1".

Comment: I have also posted a similar issue with onCall firebase function. It works perfectly fine in production but when testing I am getting this error. My posted [question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/76379302/20507115)

Comment: Have you tried using the [local emulator](https://firebase.google.com/docs/functions/local-emulator#instrument-functions) to test it?

Comment: I have tried using local emulator and testing on my iOS phone, but same result. With the emulator running, I don't even get any logs from the emulator UI when trying to run the cloud function from my mobile. Though I can call the emulated function from Postman, and everything works perfectly.

Comment: I have also tried changing the emulator host to the IP of my pc. Then I should be able to view the emulator UI from my phone browser using the host + port right? This does not work either.

Answer (score 1):

I didn't try your Cloud Function but with

```js
exports.addmessage = onCall((request) => {
    logger.info("Request: " + request.data.text);
    return {text: text}
});
```

you actually don't declare the `text` variable.

The following should do the trick:

```js
exports.addmessage = onCall((request) => {
    const text = request.data.text;
    logger.info("Request: " + text);
    return {text: text}   // Or return { text }
});
```

---

I also advise to better manage the error logging in your Cloud Function, by following the documentation: In the [CF](https://firebase.google.com/docs/functions/callable?gen=2nd#handle_errors) and in the [client](https://firebase.google.com/docs/functions/callable?gen=2nd#handle_errors_on_the_client).

Comment: I tried to implement your solution and better logging, but still the same error message. Is this an indication that the connection between client and cloud functions are not correctly setup?